# highlight sentence while play sound file

Tags: c#, javascript, browser

i have a persian sentence and a mp3 file that read this text.
I'm trying to highlight text on a sentence as an audio clip 
of that text is read to the reader.
Any ideas?

i could not use speech-2-text algorithm

please help!

Comment: Avoid headaches, make your text a SRT  and use it as subtitle while playing your mp3 with any media player (such as VLC).

Comment: my text are in a web browser control in my form and my texts are very large

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915871/how-do-i-programatically-select-text-in-a-webbrowser-control-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a  solution for this:

1. I get duration of sound file
2. second Word count in sentence
3. Divide sound duration by word count
4. and highlight each world in divided sec amount

I done it with a timer